# Different behavior calling python <script> vs <script> directly

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, rhel7

On a Red Hat 7 machine with Python 2.7.5, I'm noticing some weird behavior.

If I run the app directly (ie, `$ myApp.py`?), it'll hang when performing a certain operation. If I run it via `$ python myApp.py`, the operation succeeds. I have `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of my script (and each of its included modules as well).

I've attempted to use pdb to diagnose it, but since that's invoked via `$ python ... myApp.py`, it works!

`$ /usr/bin/env python --version` and `$ python --version` return the same value, so I suspect they're pointing at the same executable.

Is there something sneaky happening with my program loader?

Comment: Stick `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in your program's code where you want to activate pdb, and it should activate automatically even when you do `myApp.py`. Beyond that, we can't really help you.

Comment: `python myApp.py` looks for the script in the current directory, but just typing `myApp.py` generally doesn't - it looks on your path, you'd need to type `./myApp.py` to look in the current directory (unless you've included `.` in your path, which isn't recommended).  I suspect you have another version of the program, somewhere else on your path, that happens to be buggy.  Try `which myApp.py` to find out where it is.

Comment: In this case it's a fully resolved path-- $ /some/place/myApp.py, $ python /some/place/myApp.py. Seemingly little chance it could find a cloaking version...

Comment: Which operation does it "hang" on?  Can you run `strace -f` on it?

Comment: @user2357112, curious, if I run it directly from the commandline, it works.  It might be something my bash script that launches it is doing... but seemingly it's just scriptToRun=/some/place/myApp.py, ${scriptToRun} &, nothing too fancy. Could there be some setting that affects children of scripts? Some hidden Linux Max Children dealie?

Comment: @cdarke, it's a launcher script. Running strace on it (without -f as it was entirely too spammy) showed that it's hanging waiting for ... something. If I kill the PID 51491, it comes right back. That process is an ssh session, fwiw.
`wait4(51491, 0x7ffcc4477cd4, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0`
`kill(51491, SIGINT)                     = 0`
`wait4(51491, <strace stops right here>`

Comment: `wait4` is waiting for a child process to complete.  So it looks like it is hanging on an ssh session.  Can you `strace` the working call then see the difference?  You can use the `-o filename` option to `strace` to write to an output file then browse it using an editor.